Replace placeholder in python format method with a string variable?
I am trying to uniquify a string example _foo{f}_bar{b} with f ranging from 0 to F_MAX and b ranging from 0 to B_MAX. However, I'm not able to replace f with variable that holds it in the format function. Any suggestion?
reg_param = re.findall(r'{([a-z])}', in_string)

for i in range(I_MAX):
     reg_suffix = in_string.format(f=i) 

replace to something like
reg_param = re.findall(r'{([a-z])}', in_string)

for i in range(I_MAX):
     reg_suffix = in_string.format(reg_param[0]=i) 

end goal is to have strings in a list like
_foo0_bar0
_foo0_bar1
...
_foo(F_MAX-1)_bar(B_MAX-1)


You need to escape { in the regexp.

reg_param[0]=i is not how you supply keywords dynamically. You need to use **{reg_param[0]: i}

Instead of using format(), why not use re.sub()?
